# Linking PDFs (files) To Entries

Tags: google-app-maker

I am working on a PO request/approval system and would like to be able to link PDF of purchase receipts to specific datasource entries.

ex: When you search for PO-00001 you have an entry with all relevant data, plus a PDF of the receipt.

Is this possible? Is there one of the samples that does this that I could reference?

I know there is the Drive Picker Widget that allows uploading files, but I haven't seen a way to link to a specific entry. Maybe just a string with a hyperlink to a Google Drive file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is a template yet with your specific requirements but I think this is a great feature idea for the App Maker Templates. I did found an App Maker Sample that demonstrates how to use the Drive Picker which is available here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/drive-picker/

Note that the Drive Picker has special properties which are available in the Property Editor. There is a property in the Drive Picker called “**selectedDocUrl**” which can be used to bind the URL of the selected document (PDF) to a datasource entry. This property is set after the user selects the Drive file using the picker dialog.

I believe there are other ways but I was able to do a simple integration by creating an App with a datasource that has 3 fields (one of the fields will be for the PDF URL). I added a simple “Insert Form” into a Page and I placed the Drive Picker inside the Insert Form. Then I used the “selectedDocUrl” property and using bindings I simply assign it to my @datasource.item.pdf_link. Check image below:
[image]

I also included a datasource Table to the Page and added a “Link” widget at the end of the table which I styled as an Icon. I was able bind the “href” property of the Link widget to the @datasource.item.pdf_link. Upon clicking the Link icon, is simply opens a new Tab with the Drive PDF viewer and users can easily view or even download the pdf file. This is an output of the app:
[image]
Hope this helps!